# How to get probability of classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, semi-supervised-learning

I have the binary classification, I tried several models KNN, SVM, decision tree, and random forest. I have 50 000 samples, `X_train` has 50 000 rows and 2300 columns. Everything works well, but I want to build some semi-supervised model because I have some unlabeled samples. In this case, I need to get the probability of classification that I tried, but it doesn't work.

At first, I tried it for KNN

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
print(classifier.predict_proba(X_test[0]))
```

I get `[[1. 0.]]`. I don't understand why it is 1? (as first I thought it is 100%, but I get it for all test samples)

Then I tried it for the decision tree

```
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
print(classifier.predict_proba(X_test[0]))
```

I get `[[1. 0.]]` too. Why it is an integer?

Comment: What if you set `n_neighbors` to be greater than 1 or `max_depth` in your `DecisionTreeClassifier` to a small integer?

Comment: @oW_ Great! Thank you that was the problem, KNN now works, but could you give me some hint, how to set the max_depth parameter? By default it is none, but I have no idea what number to put there. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a probability of 1 because you didn't change the default parameters.

The probability for KNN is the average of all the neighbors. If there is only one neighbor `n_neighbor=1` it can only be 1 or 0.

The `DecisionTreeClassifier` expands until all the training data is classified perfectly if you don't control the depth. Again, this likely led to overfitting and to extreme probability predictions as a result. You should try different values for `max_depth` and see what works best. You can do say by performing cross validation. (If you are unfamiliar with these I recommend reading up on it first.)

Comment: I tried a different values for `max_depth`, it is working now, but I still get some features which have 1. Can I think about this that they have 100% probability?

Comment: what do you mean "features which have 1"? predictions? maybe one of your input features is perfectly correlated with your target variable. you can interpret this as your model having 100% confidence in its prediction. If you want "real" probabilities you should look into "probability calibration". scikit-learn has tools for it. just search for it.